# Maven assembly to dir and commit to svn

Tags: maven, svn, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I use the maven assembly plugin with target 'dir' to prepare a deployment package of my project. The target dir is a svn working directory and I need to perform svn dels, svn adds, and svn commit to get the repository updated. Since there is no assembly target 'svn' this is the way which works for me, but it's cumbersome and error prone.
Is there any other way to deploy into a repository? Am I missing the obvious? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by deployment package to SVN ? Are you not using a repository manager ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: No, I'm not using a repository manager because it seemed to be overkill. But I'll take a second look at his possibility.

Comment: It's not an overkill cause SVN is no repository management system nor does it have such functionality. SVN is a version control system...

Comment: I know the difference. I prefer the version control system because it grants the possibility to change local configuration files without loosing these changes with a version upgrade. E.g. in the RubyOnRails world, capistrano relies on version control systems for application deployment. I simply try to do the same thing in the java world.

Comment: The application deployment is something different which means to deploy built artifacts which are in a repository manager. Capistrano is a tool to consume built artifacts (aka applications) which is like using ansible, chef, puppet etc. in other areas. The configuration of capistrano itself should be versionized  but not the artifacts cause they are being consumed from a repository manager like Nexus (with support for ruby gems, npm, Docker, go packages, yum, NuGet etc.). Apart from that I would suggest to create a zip/tar.gz file which contains the whole application you would like to deploy.

Comment: This can be later deployed by using ansible/capistrano etc. The artifact has a unique id (groupId/artifactId/version)...